# Transform minified database object to readable keys

Tags: javascript, object, database-design, minify, database-optimization

I'm coding an app where the same data structure is saved a whole lot of times. Shortened example:

```
user-xyz: {
   displayName: 'Bla',
   email: 'bla@gmx.com',
   preferences: {
       education: 'high'
   }
}
```

To save bandwidth and database storage, I wanted to 'minify' my database keys to:

```
user-xzy: {
   dN: 'Bla',
   e: 'bla@gmx.com'
   p: {
       e: 'high'
   }
}
```

Now I have the problem that objects are coming from the database in a minified way, and I have to reassign the correct 'full' keys, so I can work with the object normally in my app. I don't want to work with the minified version, because it'd make it a lot harder for new coders to come in.

What is a good way to 'translate' the object when I have two e's (for example) as a minified key? I'd need to somehow include the object structure into my logic to select the appropriate full key.

**EDIT:** 
Redu's answer solved this problem. Now I realized, that I sometimes had objects with less keys, because the database wouldn't save 'null' values. Redu's answer wouldn't work anymore because it makes use of the index. However, I was able to modify his solution so it still works when keys are missing:

```
// mapping object
var userXYZ = {
  displayName: 'dN',
  email: 'e',
  preferences: 'p',
  p: {
    education: 'e'
  }
};

var userXYZMin = {
  dN: 'myName',
  // e: 'myName@gmx.com', -> missing key
  p: {
    e: 'elementary'
  }
};

var restoreKeys = function (original, minified) {
  return Object.keys(original)
    .reduce(function (o, k) {
      if (typeof original[k] !== "object")
        o[k] = (typeof minified[original[k]] !== "object"
          ? minified[original[k]] || ""
          : restoreKeys(original[original[k]], minified[original[k]]) || {});
      return o;
    }, {});
};
```

That just for future search requests :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided that you don't have a duplicate keys at same levels then you may do as follows;

```js
function restoreKeys(original,minified){
  var oksm = Object.keys(minified);
  return Object.keys(original)
               .reduce((o,k,i) => typeof original[k] !== "object" ? (o[k] = minified[oksm[i]],o)
                                                                  : (o[k] = restoreKeys(original[k],minified[oksm[i]]),o),{});
}

var userXYZ = {
               displayName: 'Bla',
                     email: 'bla@gmx.com',
               preferences: {
                             education: 'high'
                            }
              },

userXYZMin = {
              dN: 'myName',
               e: 'myName@gmx.com',
               p: {
                   e: 'elementary'
                  }
             },

  restored = restoreKeys(userXYZ,userXYZMin);
console.log(restored);
```

The following is the ES5 compatible version

```js
function restoreKeys(original,minified){
  var oksm = Object.keys(minified);
  return Object.keys(original)
               .reduce(function(o,k,i){
                         var oksm = Object.keys(minified);
                         o[k] = typeof original[k] !== "object" ? minified[oksm[i]]
                                                                : restoreKeys(original[k],minified[oksm[i]]);
                         return o;
                       }, {});
}

var userXYZ = {
               displayName: 'Bla',
                     email: 'bla@gmx.com',
               preferences: {
                             education: 'high'
                            }
              },

userXYZMin = {
              dN: 'myName',
               e: 'myName@gmx.com',
               p: {
                   e: 'elementary'
                  }
             },

  restored = restoreKeys(userXYZ,userXYZMin);
console.log(restored);
```

Comment: That looks good but is it possible in EC5 as well? (in the function syntax)

Comment: @Yorick Tran Sure... the second snippet should be ES5 compatible.

Comment: Specifically I don't understand the ‘(o[k] = minified[oksm[i]],o)‘ part, is the ",o" translated to "|| o"?

Comment: @Yorick Tran Well no. `(o[k] = restoreKeys(original[k],minified[oksm[i]]),o)` is in fact like `{o[k] = restoreKeys(original[k],minified[oksm[i]]); return o;}` but instead i used the parenthesis operator to fit multiple instructions in one ternary condition. (i don't use `if else` unless absolutely necessary) Though the second snippet might make a little more sense.

Comment: Aha! Now I get that. The second snippet works, big thanks for that. But it does not work if one key in the minified object is missing, right? Like that:

`userXYZMin = {
              dN: 'myName',
               p: {
                   e: 'elementary'
                  }
             }`
As far as I understand it works with the index, which would be different if 'email' for example was missing?

Comment: @Yorick Tran.. Sure the master object (with meaningful property names) must perfectly match the minified ones in structure. However since you minify from the original yourself, you can take a precaution if a property is missing and place a dummy one with correct type.

Comment: I realized the db does not save null values so sometimes keys are missing. I found a solution however through adjusting the mapping (original) object. Thank you for your help! :)